# Hide files ending in tilde

Tags: command-line

These backup files clutter up my screen when I'm trying to navigate.

How do I hide files ending in a tilde so `ls` doesn't show them and only `ls -a` does. That is, I want them to behave like files which are preceded by a period.

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
 alias ls='ls --hide="*~"'
```

to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash.aliases` or where ever you define your shell aliases.

Comment: This works, but I lose the highlighting that `ls` does. How do I keep the highlighting?

Comment: Try `alias ls='ls --hide="*~" --color=auto'`

Comment: `ls --ignore-backups` is the generalization.

Comment: And short-form of `--ignore-backups` is `-B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the files to be hidden. Use: `ls --hide=*~`.

Answer (score 1):

It was in the comments, but here's an answer:

```
ls --ignore-backups 
ls -B
```